# Import or Sync Symbols between Sketch Files

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

I have various symbols in various .sketch files, such as Font Awesome, Bootstrap UI, etc...  I would like to have access to all symbols in other files too - or ideally I would like to make specific symbols as 'global' while others can remain accessible only to the sketch file they're in. Is that possible?

Also, where does Sketch 'keep' these symbols...  e.g. in the [Font-Awesome-Symbols-for-Sketch](https://github.com/sethlilly/Font-Awesome-Symbols-for-Sketch) , the symbols remain accessible to insert, even after you delete any pages. They are NOT (as is frequently suggested in tutorials/posts) actually placed on a canvas. So where are they and how can I copy them?

There is a plugins for [importing symbols from another sketch file](https://github.com/kmerc/sketch-import-symbols). Unfortunately, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

After updating from my App Store version of Sketch (3.4.2) to the latest 3.4.4 version of Sketch, the plugin (https://github.com/kmerc/sketch-import-symbols/) now works perfectly: it imports sketch icons from any other sketch file into the current one. You can install it easily with the Sketch Toolbox (a great way to find and install a lot of different plugins for Sketch - http://sketchtoolbox.com/) or directly from the github link above.

Comment: Really hoping someone picks up development of SketchToolbox again. It's a great utility.